# Systems trigger when CPU usage is low

Tags: systemd, cpu-usage, job-control

## Background

There is a server that is used to run simulations that I was just invited to. Unfortunately, instead of some reasonable job manager (i.e., `slurm`) they have a system where only one big job can run at a time (others are killed). If I want to run something I first check top and if no ones using it I can run my job.

## Question

So I would like to have a system where I can say something like "if there's less than 20% CPU usage for 1 minute, run my job."

Is there a way to do this using systemd?

## Bonus points

I'd also like to have a folder where I can just copy things to and have them run. My current idea is to have a `DirectoryNotEmpty` trigger and somehow pairing it with the above. But I also don't know how to say "if both of these are true" in systemd. Any help here is appreciated.